# Add meta tags to a SPA html page with Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions, single-page-application, quasar-framework

I've developed a SPA using VueJS, Quasar, and Firebase. Currently, the app is hosted on Firebase and makes use of the Storage and the Firestore Database features. I've encountered an issue regarding a simple yet very useful feature, Facebook/Twitter/Linkedin social share buttons(html 'a' tags that pass the URL to be shared). After much reading into the matter, I've come to understand these social platforms use crawlers to subtract certain open graph 'meta' tags from the served HTML to form a cohesive post that includes Images, Title, Description.

The obstacle I'm facing is that this being a SPA, the same static HTML is always served from the hosting service(Firebase). This means that the meta tags that would need to be unique per different route can't be changed, for example, injected using javascript. I've reached this conclusion after hours of painstakingly trying to find a work-around using different injection methods and libraries even trying to see if NuxtJs would somehow be of help. Now I understand that logically this cannot work since the same HTML file will always be served in a SPA.

Based on my current understanding, which might be wrong, I will need to implement Cloud Functions(sort of a server provided by google) in order to intercept the HTML requests from these crawlers and somehow serve a server-rendered HTML file containing these meta tags.

My questions for anyone that has stumbled upon something similar would be:

1. First of all is there something I'm missing and there is a way of serving a rendered HTML file with the current setup?
2. Is there a way of implementing Cloud Functions to intercept requests from these crawlers or otherwise continue the current SPA flow?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vue, but from my understanding Nuxt is used for SSR. My question: why wouldn't this work, logically? SSR generates plain HTML, which the crawler can read, and then the SPA framework "hydrates".

Comment: SSR is a foreign area to me, i have never touched it before. Is it usually hard to transition an already written app to an SSR version of itself?

Comment: As someone coming from a React background, I would say no, not at all. However, Vue might be different, I do not know. Take a look: https://itnext.io/how-to-create-a-ssr-serverless-app-with-firebase-nuxt-js-in-an-hour-6e6e03d0b3b8

Comment: After some reading on the matter i can agree that it seems a true nightmare. It would require writing a lot of things from scratch

Comment: I’m not sure whether you can implement some sort of logic in Firestore which intercepts requests then re-writes the generated HTML. Perhaps you can. But how would you sync SPA routes and the rewritten routes? What if dynamic data is present? It would effectively result in having to rewrite part of your business logic. With a lot of caveats. If SSR looks like a nightmare, this is a minefield in hell.

Comment: Apparently, there is a way of achieving this with Cloud Functions -> https://medium.com/@eliaecoyote/how-i-achieved-seo-on-spa-with-firebase-cloud-functions-4efee0a002b7, i have yet to understand how to make this work though